# z-index bug with animated transform

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm making my personal website and encounter this problem.

On top left of the corner there's a button. It's supposed to be clickable but for some reason it is hidden behind an image (in a sense that you cannot interact with it but you can still see it). Using my debug skill, it leads me to a conclusion that the animated image (with `-webkit-transform`) (note you cannot test this on Firefox or other browser yet) is probably the reason that mess up the priority of elements.

I tried to fix it with `z-index` 100 or 10000 but still no work. Strangely, if I remove the elements `.bg` number 2,3,4, the button is clickable again.

If anyone can please tell me if it's a browser bug and if there's a workaround for it.

My website: http://iflyingangel.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`position:fixed` creates a new stacking context, so `z-index` isn't behaving as you would expect: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements

Try this simple fix, let me know if it works for you:

```
.bg { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: That's it... simple and effective, +1